# how do i redirect output from tailf & grep to a file

Tags: bash, grep, tail, output

All I wanted is to grep for specific lines in an ongoing log and re-direct it to some file..

```
tailf log | grep "some words"
```

Now, I want the above command output to get re-directed to some file in on-going basis....

I tried,

```
tailf log | grep "some words" >> file
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: what happen ? empty file ? file with jump line ? nothing ? tailf only access file when modify. are you sure your log is not empty ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is buffering.

Use the `--line-buffered` option to force `grep` to flush the buffer after every line:

```
tailf log | grep --line-buffered "some words" >> file
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. I have a little further requirement.. I will try that myself and see how it goes.. Thank you so much..